# How to allow the mouse to work when using PointerLockControls?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating a 3d art gallery using three.js. I'm using PointerLockControls to look around.

I want the art on the walls of my gallery to be able to be clicked so a pop up can show up after clicking it and display information, but PointerLockControls seems to disable clicking and/or using the mouse in general for anything that is not looking around.

How can I enable the click and the mouse cursor to be displayed while still using PointerLockControls?

Tried adding this eventlistener for the click but it just doesn't work. I even added a console.log and it sends no message to my console.
Tried adding the console.log to the renderer's domElement and to the document and it does work. The problem seems to be the artowrk.

Everything displays just fine, but I can't get that pop up to show. Here's the code for that segment.

Here is my code :

```
let art2Texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/art/2.png');
        
        const art2Geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(8, 8);
        const art2Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map: art2Texture
        });
        
        const art2 = new THREE.Mesh(art2Geometry, art2Material);
        
        art2.position.z = -49.9;
        art2.position.y = 3.5;
        
        art2.userData = {
  name: 'Artwork 2',
  description: 'This is the description of Artwork 2',
  link: 'https://here-goes-the-link',
};

art2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Artwork 2 clicked!');
    const popup = document.createElement('div');
  popup.className = 'popup';

  const title = document.createElement('h2');
  title.textContent = art2.userData.name;

  const description = document.createElement('p');
  description.textContent = art2.userData.description;

  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = art2.userData.link;
  link.target = '_blank';
  link.textContent = 'View on OpenSea';

  popup.appendChild(title);
  popup.appendChild(description);
  popup.appendChild(link);

  document.body.appendChild(popup);
});

// CSS for the pop-up
const popupCSS = `
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.popup a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 16px;
}
`;

const popupStyle = document.createElement('style');
popupStyle.textContent = popupCSS;

document.head.appendChild(popupStyle);
        scene.add(art2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't `.addEventListener("click")` to a Mesh, because that's a property of HTMLElements. Instead you could add a click event listener to the canvas, and then find out what element is in the middle of the screen [with a `Raycaster`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster).

You can go through [this official example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes) to find out which object the mouse is pointing at. Just click the bottom `< >` icon to see its source code.